# Concatenating Dataframes with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am working on a dataset in Pandas & Python 3 and have written the following code to establish survival rates per sex per class:

```
survivors = pd.DataFrame('titanic.csv')
survivors = titanic.iloc[:, :3]
df = survivors.groupby(by = ['sex', 'pclass']).sum()
```

[image]

I have also written the following code to establish the percentage of each survival rate per sex per class:

```
total = np.sum(df['survived'])
perc = [(df['survived'][i]/total)*100 for i in range(len(df['survived']))]
pip = pd.DataFrame({"Percentage": perc})
```

[image]

I would like to merge/concatenate the two dataframes and together, so that the 'percentage' value sits next to the corresponding 'survived' value. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can do that directly, like this `df['Percentage']=df['survived'][i]/total)*100 for i in range(len(df['survived'])` good luck.

Comment: just do ```df['Percentage']=(df['survived']/total)*100``` you don't need the ```for loop```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new DataFrame for percentage values and concatenating it, I would suggest that you create the percentage column in the same DataFrame, likewise:

```
df['Percentage']=df['survived'][i]/total)*100 for i in range(len(df['survived'])
```

I used the above code just for answering the concatenating part and used your code as is for the calculation part. A better way would be to use the below code:

```
df['Percentage']= (df['survived']/total) * 100
```